# Perl: speed of s/// with variable in replacement

Tags: perl

This:

```
while($read=sysread(STDIN,$buf,32760)) {
    $buf=~s/\r/posttag\rpretag\t/go;
    $buf=~s/\n/posttag\npretag\t/go;
    syswrite(STDOUT,$buf);
}
```

delivers ~200 MB/s on my system.

This:

```
my $pretag = "pretag";
my $posttag = "posttag";
while($read=sysread(STDIN,$buf,32760)) {
    $buf=~s/\r/$posttag\r$pretag\t/go;
    $buf=~s/\n/$posttag\n$pretag\t/go;
    syswrite(STDOUT,$buf);
}
```

delivers ~100 MB/s on my system.

Why?

I thought that when I had used `/o` it should not matter if the content is a variable or a fixed string. Is there an easy way I can get the speed of the first?

Comment: The `o` flag is to compile the regexp once. The variables are in the replacement part, not the regexp part here.

Comment: FWIW, in my tests, when doing `my $repl = "$posttag\r$pretag\t"` and then `$buf=~s/\r/$repl/g`, I don't see any slow down compared to a fixed replacement.

Comment: I think the answer is that when the replacement is only a single (unchanging) variable (as in @StephaneChazelas comment, then there is no slow down, but when the replacement is an expression with multiple interpolations (as in Ole's original examples), then there will/might be a slow down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that regexp recompilation is to blame?
You can get information about what perl is doing with your regexps using

```
use re 'debug';
```

In second case you introduce interpolated string in s//HERE/ and perl interpolates it with each iteration.

Try to rewrite like

```
my $pretag = 'pretag';
my $posttag = 'posttag';
my $first_replace = "$posttag\r$pretag\t";
my $second_replace = "$posttag\n$pretag\t";
while($read=sysread(STDIN,$buf,32760)) {
    $buf=~s/\r/$first_replace/go;
    $buf=~s/\n/$second_replace/go;
    syswrite(STDOUT,$buf);
}
```

Comment: How can I tell Perl not to interpolate it every time? It seems each interpolation slow it down.

Comment: doesn't the above example help?

Comment: Here , `$pretag` & `$posttag` will be interpolated **once** into `$first_replace` & into `$second_replace` but these will be interpolated **every time** into the regex ! Question Ex1 contains no interpolation (fast) & Question Ex2 contains interpolation (slow) ( Both given by OP @OleTange ) & Answer Ex contains interpolation (slow) !!

Answer (score 6):

Per the `perlop` [documentation](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer) for the `/o` flag, emphasis added:

> "s/**PATTERN**/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer"
>
> If you want the **pattern** compiled only once the first time the variable is interpolated, use the "/o" option.

Therefore `/o` is only relevant to the **pattern**, not the replacement. Even then some programmers consider `/o` to be a problem, and will not use it, with the typical sentiment running along the lines of:

> < pragma-> perlre#Modifiers: o  - pretend to optimize your code, but actually introduce bugs

If I had to interpolate the Right-Hand-Side or replacement in advance, I'd probably use [Sub::Quote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Quote) or similar to turn the RHS into static strings.